# AngulaJS Cannot reference service - Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting an error in the form `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LoginServiceProvider <- LoginService <- LoginController...` when trying to implement a service. I am new to angular and suspect that I am missing something obvious. I've tried looking through the error with non-minified JS but nothing looks too helpful. I've triple checked spellings, looked through numerous examples with no progress. Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

Full error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LoginServiceProvider <- LoginService <- LoginController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=LoginServiceProvider%20%3C-%20LoginService%20%3C-%20LoginController
Stack trace:
minErr/<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:66:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4789:19
getService@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4944:32
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4794:28
getService@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4944:32
injectionArgs@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4969:58
instantiate@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:5015:18
$controller@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:10877:18
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular-        route/angular-route.js:1214:26
bind/<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:1341:15
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:10419:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:9808:11
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:9048:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:8913:30
lazyCompilation@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:9304:16
boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:9091:16
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:9858:20
update@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js:1172:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:18498:15
commitRoute/</<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js:734:19
processQueue@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:16843:37
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:16887:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:17982:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:18280:13
done@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:12378:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:12604:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:12532:9
```

app.js

```
angular.module('rateApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'appRoutes',
  'MainCtrl',
  'LoginCtrl', 'LoginService'
]);
```

appRoutes.js

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })
    // Login page
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
     });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

controllers/LoginCtrl.js

```
angular.module('LoginCtrl', []).controller('LoginController',    function($scope, LoginService) {
   $scope.departments = LoginService.getAllDepartments();
   $scope.faculties = LoginService.getAllFaculties();
});
```

services/LoginService.js

```
angular.module('LoginService', []).factory('Login', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        // Get all the known departments
        getAllDepartments: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/dept/all');
        },
        // Get all the known faculties 
        getAllFaculties: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/faculties/all');
        }
    }
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>App</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <!-- custom styles -->
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/LoginService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="rateApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You controller should inject **`Login`** instead of **`LoginService`**, because **`LoginService`** is a module

```
angular.module('LoginCtrl', []).controller('LoginController',function($scope, Login) {
   $scope.departments = Login.getAllDepartments();
   $scope.faculties = Login.getAllFaculties();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`angular.module('appRoutes', [])` to `angular.module('appRoutes', ['LoginCtrl'])`

and

`angular.module('LoginCtrl', ['LoginService'])` to `angular.module('LoginCtrl', [])`

It looks like the dependency (the module) wasn't injected properly into the module.